# What is required in to make a property with the [ServiceDepenency] attribute resolve?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a custom helper class, and I want to use the `[ServiceDepenency]` attribute to obtain a value.

```
public class MyHelper
{
    private WorkItem _workItem;

    [ServiceDependency]
    public WorkItem MyWorkItem
    {
        get { return _workItem; }
        set { _workItem = value; }
    }
}
```

This seems to work absolutely fine in other areas of the application I'm working in, however it doesn't work with my custom helper class. The `set` method is never called.

This works fine in another service class of the same project / namespace. The only difference there, is the Service class contains a `[Service]` attribute, and is obtained using `WorkItem.Services.Get<IMyService>` instead of using `new MyHelper()` in places it's needed.

```
[Service(typeof(IMyService))]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private WorkItem _workItem;

    [ServiceDependency]
    public WorkItem MyWorkItem
    {
        get { return _workItem; }
        set { _workItem = value; }
    }
}
```

It also appears to work fine on our `BasePresenter` class, which as far as I can tell contains no special attributes. This is in a different library though, and is abstracted enough that I could be missing something with it.

```
public abstract class BasePresenter
{
    private WorkItem _workItem;

    [ServiceDependency]
    public WorkItem MyWorkItem
    {
        get { return _workItem; }
        set { _workItem = value; }
    }
}
```

What exactly is needed in order to get CAB to inject this value whenever an instance of the `MyHelper` class is created?

I'm working with .Net 3.5, and I don't know a whole lot about the CAB system.